# Geography at the pixel level

Tags: cipher, knowledge, language, geography

> [image]
>   ([enlarged version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JRHs.png))

The answer is a group of islands.

> More properly "geography and language", I suppose.

Comment: I'll just take a moment to appreciate how cleverly made these puzzles are. @jafe you are ingenious. I wonder what you'll do seven puzzles later when you reach your 200th! :D

Comment: @useruser477343 Thanks for the kind words :) Your #100 is just around the corner as well! Anything special planned?

Comment: This is an amazing puzzle - so much packed into so little. You've got a real gift for puzzlecraft and presentation. If you're not publishing somewhere, you should be :)

Comment: Oh, wait, really?! I had no idea xD Perhaps I will plan something special... perhaps a meta-puzzle will do... we'll soon see ;)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Looks like

> Each section of the image is an 8-letter geographical location or adjective:
>  [image]
>  1 WOODRING: QR code
>  2 WATZMANN: Chappe system for semaphore telegraph
>  3 VICTORIA: just upside-down (and pixelated)
>  4 TITICACA: Arabic
>  5 WARUSAWA: Japanese Braille
>  6 WELIRANG: Morse code
>  7 MEDELPAD: hexadecimal ASCII
>  8 SURINAME: Bopomofo
>  9 SHERWOOD: International Phonetic Alphabet
>  10 THAILAND: in the negative space
>  11 SIHLWALD: plain text, spaced out with empty lines
>  12 GODAVARI: tap code
>  13 MONROVIA: faces of dice and mathematical operations, decoded with successive  results as A1Z26
>  14 RIONEGRO: higher rows shifted one pixel right
>  15 NAGALAND: Cyrillic
>  16 MOLDOVAN: number the inside spaces 1-26, read off each piece as A1Z26
>  17 MICHIGAN: Shavian
>  18 SAARLAND: flag semaphore
>  19 DEMERARA: jigsaw puzzle
>  20 MANDARIN: Japanese katakana
>  21 MANDINKA: Moon type
>  22 EYREWELL: binary in negative space
>  23 BOTSWANA: Roman numerals in negative space (A1Z26)
>  24 CANBERRA: Pigpen cipher
>  25 FUNAFUTI: Futhark runes
>  26 KINGSTON: Deseret
>  27 WINNIPEG: each row in the box is binary
>  28 KIRIBATI: Hebrew
>  29 SINDARIN: plain text, just really small
>  30 BELGOROD: T-shaped "arrows" tell the direction of the next letter, and number of pixels behind them tell how far to move.
>  31 GISHWATI: each row has 26 spaces, read black pixels as A1Z26
>  32 MISSOURI: Greek

Once all of the places are found,

> these fit in 8 categories, having 4 entries each:
>
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Mountains:** **W**ATZMANN, **W**ARUSAWA, **W**ELIRANG, **W**OODRING
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Lakes:** V**I**CTORIA, T**I**TICACA, W**I**NNIPEG, M**I**CHIGAN
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Capital cities:** MO**N**ROVIA, CA**N**BERRA, FU**N**AFUTI, KI**N**GSTON
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Languages:** MOL**D**OVAN, MAN**D**INKA, MAN**D**ARIN, SIN**D**ARIN.
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Forests:** SHER**W**OOD, SIHL**W**ALD, EYRE**W**ELL, GISH**W**ATI
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Countries/sovereign states:** THAIL**A**ND, SURIN**A**ME, BOTSW**A**NA, KIRIB**A**TI
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Rivers:** GODAVA**R**I, RIO NEG**R**O, MISSOU**R**I, DEMERA**R**A
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Provinces/territories:** MEDELPA**D**, NAGALAN**D**, SAARLAN**D**, BELGORO**D**
>
>  Inside each category all the entries have a common letter in the same position, and no letter position is the same between any two categories. These letters spell out WINDWARD, which refers to the **Windward Islands.**

Comment: I've numbered the individual puzzles, so now it will be easier to refer to them.

Comment: Everything's correct. Nice work, everyone!

Comment: Comments by multiple contributors adding to the solution have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92386/discussion-on-answer-by-elias-geography-at-the-pixel-level) to preserve their authors without spoiling the solutions. Great teamwork everyone who contributed: [elias](/users/8822), [Rémi Henry](/users/56494), [Ivan García Topete](/users/58478), [Brandon_J](/users/56016), [Barker](/users/42302), [M Oehm](/users/9860), and [PiIsNot3](/users/57742), plus the folks who left partial answers :)

Answer (score 12):

Partial (refer to community wiki for notation)

1:

> woodring (by OmegaKrypton)

5:

> warusawa [braille] (by elias)

6:

> welirang [morse] (by elias) - typo in puzzle, a space missing between the last two characters

9:

> sherwood (by OmegaKrypton)

27:

> Winnipeg (by Gremlin) - binary pixels

Answer (score 11):

Some more:

> 4. Titicaca (Arabic)
>  12. Godavari (tap code)
>  22. Eyrewell (inverse binary)
>  25. Funafuti (futhark)
>  28. Kiribati (Hebrew)
>  32. Missouri (Greek)

Other remarks:

> The katakana one (20) looks to me as if it says "ma so da ri so" which I can't identify.

Comment: ma-so-da-ri-so seems two be 2 characters too long, so probably 'so' needs to be replaced with a single character. mandarin looks like a good solution, but how is that geographical?

Comment: Dunno! I am just as puzzled as you are.

Comment: Ech, I redrew that letter in #20 so many times and now that I look at it it still looks wrong... Mandarin is correct.

Answer (score 11):

**Partial**

8.

> SURIBAME(?) (Taiwanese Mandarin Zhuyin) -> I think this one should be SURINAME, but the N character is kinda wonky...

29.

> SINDARIN (very pixelated letters)

(Will add more as I figure them out)

As for the meta, I have found that

> every geographic location can fit into one of eight categories, with each category having four locations - somewhat like a connect wall. I’ve listed the categories here, along with the locations and the regions they represent:
>
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Mountains:** WATZMANN (German), WARUSAWA (Japan), WELIRANG (Indonesia), WOODRING (United States)
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Lakes:** VICTORIA (Tanzania/Uganda), TITICACA (Peru/Bolivia), WINNIPEG (Canada), ???
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Forests:** SHERWOOD (England), SIHLWALD (Switzerland), EYREWELL (New Zealand), GISHWATI (Rwanda)
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Provinces/territories:** MEDELPAD (Sweden), NAGALAND (India), SAARLAND (Germany), DEMERARA (Guyana)
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Countries/sovereign states:** THAILAND (Asia), SURINAME (South America), BOTSWANA (Africa), KIRIBATI (Micronesia/Oceania)
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Rivers:** GODAVARI (India), RIO NEGRO (Brazil/Venezuela/Colombia), MISSOURI (United States), ???
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Capital cities:** MONROVIA (Liberia), CANBERRA (Australia), FUNAFUTI (Tuvalu), ???
>  $ \quad \bullet $ **Languages:** MOLDOVAN (Moldova), MANDINKA (Ivory Coast), MANDARIN (China), SINDARIN (fictional/Middle-earth)
>
>  So the three unsolved clues must fit into one of three categories: lakes, rivers, and capital cities. Maybe that’ll make things a bit easier?

I’ll add this to the community wiki once the other three clues are solved.

Comment: Nice observation, I think I've found the solution based on your idea. I've added it to the community wiki - and it will help us finding the missing 3 entries as well.

Comment: Demerara and Thailand probably should be swapped (if my next observation is correct)

Answer (score 10):

20.

> Mandarin (japanese katakana -> マンダリン)

@ user Gareth McCaughan♦
I agree that its a bit difficult since the "so"and "n" look a lot like eachother and since its pixels it looks more like a "so"

Answer (score 10):

Some more:

14.

> Rio Negro (every row is shifted to the right one pixel further)

17.

> Michigan (in [Shavian alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shavian_alphabet))

31.

> Gishwati (every row has one pixel, number of pixel corresponds to alphabet number)

Additionally, regarding the final answer,

> I think that after all the eight-letter words are discovered, we'll find that there's exactly one letter for each of the 8 positions that doesn't occur in any of the words.

Comment: I don't think your guess about the final extraction can be right. E.g., the last letters so far are all ADIGLNO and only eight answers are un-found, so there's no way to eliminate all but one of the possibilities.

Comment: (I'm guessing _majority_ rather than _omission_.)

Comment: (Though if so then I think at least one of the current majorities must be misleading.)

Answer (score 10):

2:

> WATZMANN - Semaphore Telegraph Chappe System

Comment: Hey, you found it, too!

Answer (score 10):

A guess at the final answer based on the clues everyone else solved and Gareth McCaughan's predicted method:

> So far taking the most common letter in each position gives:
>  `MINDWANA`
>  That's not an island group, but if we look at the second most common letters:
>  `WARRIORD`
>  So if the missing answers allow the second placed letter to overtake the current leader in positions 1, 7, and 8, we get:
>  `WINDWARD` for the [Windward Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windward_Islands).

Answer (score 9):

16.

> We have : 13, 15     ; 12     ; 4, 15, 22     ; 1, 14.
>
>  It gives us : M O ; L; D O V; A N.
>  Moldovan

Answer (score 9):

21:

> MANDINKA written in [Moon type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_type)

Answer (score 7):

#26

> is **Kingston** in the [Deseret alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deseret_alphabet).

#30

> is **Belgorod**. Start at the beginning of the alphabet. For each arrow, add an offset. Upwards arrows go forward in the alphabet, downward arrows go backwards: start + 2 → B + 3 → E + 7 → L and so on.