# Crossword gone overboard

Tags: knowledge, no-computers, chess, geography, crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part 24 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > By the time you receive this message, I may have already returned from my trip. Today I visited a luxurious mansion built by an important person. I hope your board game skills are not rusty, because you'll need them for today's puzzle!
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Large inlet
>   5. Local name for Scotland
>   9. More delicate
>   10. A place where a fly is a nuisance
>   11. An African country or its capital city
>   15. Less feral
>   16. A Uruk-hai, for example
>   18. Native of an Arab state
>   19. Zilch
>   20. Precious stone
>   21. Card below trey
>   22. Evaluated
>
> **Down**
>   1. Perfect is the enemy of —
>   2. Prefix for -cycle or -brow
>   3. Short-range network
>   4. — as a fiddle
>   5. Arsenals
>   6. Instead of = in — of
>   7. Grandmaster Larsen
>   8. Newspaper piece
>   12. Outlaw assassinated by coward
>   13. Members of the clergy
>   14. Arizona landmark: Horseshoe —
>   15. Ancient Roman attire
>   16. Legal obligation
>   17. Sushi ingredient

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[Thousands and thousands of words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84464)*".</sub>

Comment: Man, everyone's answers below was each on 9 upvotes. Glad to have upvoted each and awarded three answer badges, hehe. Great puzzle, jafe! Is the series still continuing? (Not that I can solve it :P)

Comment: @MrPie Thanks! The series has already finished. The last puzzle is [number 26](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84494). As you may know, the entire series was a result of [a comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81556/geography-at-the-pixel-level#comment238559_81556) you made back in April :)

Comment: I remember that! Ahhh, so it was one big meta puzzle! Well, I'm honoured to have inspired you to make such a big puzzle, coming from me who can just pull off a riddle, haha. Fun fact: **Gladys series = Less easy grid.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once again, I feel like I’m swooping in and snatching the answer, using the excellent solutions already provided by @Glorfindel for the chess puzzles and @Jay for the crossword. Thanks to you both!

If we:

> Only use white’s moves for the chess solutions per @Glorfindel’s answer, and then map them accordingly according to @Jay’s crossword, we get [Tjong a Fie](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tjong_A_Fie_Mansion) which is a luxurious mansion in North Sumatra, Indonesia.

Specifically:

> a4: T 
>  b5: J 
>  a6: O 
>  b7: N 
>  a8: G 
>  — 
>  c7: A 
>  — 
>  d8: F 
>  f7: I 
>  g7: E

Answer (score 11):

Partial answer with solutions for the chess problems:

> Top left: white to move mates in 5, with 1. Rxa4+ Kc5 2. Rb5+ Kd6 3. Ra6+ Kc7 (or Kd7 or Ke7) 4. Rb7+ Kc8 (or Kd8 or Ke8 or Kf8) 5. Ra8#
>  Top right: white to move mates in 1, with 1. Nxc7# (so-called 'smothered mate')
>  Bottom left: white to move mates in 3, with 1. Rd8+ Qxd8 2. Qxf7+ Kh8 3. Qxg7#

([no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers); these were easy enough to figure out without [Stockfish](https://stockfishchess.org/))

Note that

> for every problem, the first move is to a square which has a number in the bottom right diagram (a4 = 15, c7 = 9, d8 = 4). I'm not sure if this is relevant, though.

Answer (score 11):

Partial answer with the crossword

> `..abcdefgh`
> `.`
> `8 gulfalba`
> `7 onairier`
> `6 ointment`
> `5 djibouti`
> `4 tamerorc`
> `3 omaninil`
> `2 gemdeuce`
> `1 assessed`

Using the answer from Glorfindel to try and find the code

> a4 T
>  c5 I
>  b5 J
>  d6 T
>  a6 O
>  c7 A
>  b7 N
>  c8 L
>  a8 G
>  c7 A
>  d8 F
>  d8 F
>  f7 I
>  h8 A
>  g7 E