# Thousands and thousands of words

Tags: visual, rebus, geography, cryptic-clues, crossword-clues

<sub>This puzzle is part 25 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > And so my journey has come to an end. This is my last destination. I have spent the day walking around in a shopping mall, trying to find the perfect souvenirs. I hope you have enjoyed my puzzles as much as I have enjoyed making them. I'll send you one more message once I get home to let you know the correct answers to my puzzles.
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

**Part 1**

> [image]

**Part 2**

> 1. The news put me in touch with strange gases (7)
>   2. Strike head of nail in long piece of tree (3)
>   3. Landlord engaged in toilet terrorism (6)
>   4. Venereal disease dropped from satellite to troublemaker (4)
>   5. Musician to almost guide make-up artist (9)
>   6. Fear to shoot rare ogre evenly (6)
>   7. Organize disorganized decoration (10)
>   8. Some gold estimated for first-born (6)

**Part 3**

> 1. A psychic; neither large nor small (6)
>   2. Solution with a high pH value (4)
>   3. Communication sent by post (6)
>   4. Slapping or walking musician (7)
>   5. JFK and MLK, for example (8)
>   6. New and original (5)
>   7. Enemy of the Allies (4)
>   8. The resolution of a legal dispute (10)

---

<sub>Gladys' journey will conclude in "*[More important than the destination](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84494)*".

Image credits: 4. Ixnayonthetimmay, CC BY-SA 3.0; 5.1 Steven Depolo, CC BY 2.0; 5.2 Rick Marshall, CC BY 2.0; 8.1 Allan warren, CC BY-SA 3.0; 8.2 Bruce Marlin, CC BY-SA 3.0</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Complete Solution**

Part 1:

> 1. laTEX + T = TEXT. (Thanks, @Omega Krypton!) 
>  2. NAT King Cole + URAL mountains = NATURAL. 
>  3. SCARLETT O'Hara - T = SCARLET. 
>  4. VICI + centre of hOUSe = VICIOUS. (Thanks, @masterX244!) 
>  5. VANILLA ICE CREAM - VANILLA ICE = CREAM. 
>  6. First half of clownfish = CLOWN. (Thanks, @Omega Krypton!) 
>  7. Vertigo - go + cal = VERTICAL. 
>  8. Prince PHILIP + PINE = PHILIPPINE. (Thanks, @Omega Krypton!)

Part 2:

> 1. The news put me in touch with strange gases (7) 
>  ME + gases rearranged SSAGE = MESSAGE (thanks, @JonMark Perry!) 
>  2. Strike head of nail in long piece of tree (3) 
>  LONG - head of nail N = LOG. 
>  3. Landlord engaged in toilet terrorism (6) 
>  toiLET TERrorism = LETTER (def. landlord). 
>  4. Venereal disease dropped from satellite to troublemaker (4) 
>  SPUTNIK - STI = PUNK. 
>  5. Musician to almost guide make-up artist (9) 
>  almost GUIde artist rearranged TARIST = GUITARIST. 
>  6. Fear to shoot rare ogre evenly (6) 
>  sHoOt RaRe OgRe evenly = HORROR. 
>  7. Organize disorganized decoration (10) 
>  rearrange decoration = COORDINATE (thanks, @Omega Krypton!) 
>  8. Some gold estimated for first-born (6) 
>  gOLD ESTimated = OLDEST.

Part 3:

> 1. A psychic; neither large nor small (6) 
>  MEDIUM 
>  2. Solution with a high pH value (4) 
>  BASE (R.I.P. my chemistry skills haha....*high* is base and *low* is acid) 
>  3. Communication sent by post (6) 
>  LETTER 
>  4. Slapping or walking musician (7) 
>  [slapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slapping_(music)) and [walking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bassline#Walking_bass) are bass terms, so the musician is a BASSIST. 
>  5. JFK or MLK, for example (8) 
>  INITIALS (although I didn't see it, @JonMark Perry got this at the same time or before me. Thanks very much!!) 
>  6. New and original (5) 
>  NOVEL 
>  7. Enemy of the Allies (4) 
>  AXIS 
>  8. The resolution of a legal dispute (10) 
>  SETTLEMENT

Putting it all together:

> 1. TEXT MESSAGE MEDIUM = **[SMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS)**. 
>  2. NATURAL LOG BASE = **[E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm)**. 
>  3. SCARLET LETTER LETTER = **[A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scarlet_Letter#Symbols)**. 
>  4. VICIOUS PUNK BASSIST = **[SID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sid_Vicious)**. 
>  5. CREAM GUITARIST INITIALS = **[EC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Clapton)**. 
>  6. CLOWN HORROR NOVEL = **[IT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_(novel))**. 
>  7. VERTICAL COORDINATE AXIS = **[Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)**. 
>  8. OLDEST PHILIPPINE SETTLEMENT = **[CEBU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cebu_City)**.

Much gratitude to @athin for finding the final solution:

> [**SM SEASIDE CITY CEBU**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SM_Seaside_City_Cebu) in Cebu City, Philippines.

Comment: Meta part, no 7: ROT13(Iregvpny Pbbeqvangr Nkvf vf L)

Comment: A landlord is a LET-er

Comment: I guess I know the final answer which is ROT13(FZF R N FVQ RP VG L PROH)

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I've finished up and credited you for Part III-5 -- didn't see your answer before but great find!

Comment: You get the tick! That said, it's ok to just post the answer separately, @athin... I'm sure El-Guest of all people wouldn't have minded ([ref](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/84409/41973)) :)

Comment: Only one ref, @jafe? ;P I'm sure I've done that more than once... that said, I definitely agree with jafe, athin!! But I appreciate the collaboration!

Comment: Haha no worries, it just feels weird for me to post a short final answer while others are writing a comprehensive long essay for their answers XD Great collab tho, glad to help! ^^

Answer (score 4):

Part 1

1

> **TEXT**: La**TEX** + **T**

2(partial)

> Nat King Cole + ?

3

> **HARLEY**: Vivien Leigh/ Vivian Mary **Hartley** - **T**

4(partial)

> **VICI** + house?

5

> Vanilla ice cream - Vanilla ice cap = **CONE**!

6

> **Clown** (first half of clownfish)

7(partial)

> **VERTICAL**: Vertigo - go + cal (4.184J) (thank you, @El-Guest!)

8

> **PHILIPPINE**: Prince Philip + Pine

---

Part 2

7 Organize disorganized decoration (10)

> COORDINATE, anagram of decoration, def = organize

---

Meta

1

> **Paper/Newspaper**: Text news medium

6

> **IT**: Clown horror novel

7

> **Y**: Vertical Coordinate Axis (thank you, @athin!)

8

> **Pleistocene**: Oldest Phillipine settlement

Answer (score 4):

Part 2:

1.

> ME+SSAGE (strange gases) = news

Part 3:

5.

> INITIALS

Answer (score 2):

Part 1 picture 4 Guess

> Vici + House (Box not complete House) vicious?

Comment: That's really clever, well done!!