# More important than the destination

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, geography, metapuzzles

<sub>This puzzle is the 26th and final part of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. If you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

<sub>Spoiler alert: This puzzle **gives away the answers** to the previous parts in the series.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > As promised, I'm sending you the correct answers to the puzzles I have sent you during my travels. Thank you for following my journey through to the end. I wish you all the best.
> >
> > One last question: What do you think I got out of my trip?
> >
> > Love, Gladys.

> 1. [Heinz Memorial Chapel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinz_Memorial_Chapel), Pittsburgh
>  2. [Emerald Necklace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerald_Necklace), Boston
>  3. [Tredegar Iron Works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tredegar_Iron_Works), Richmond
>  4. [International Church of Cannabis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Church_of_Cannabis), Denver
>  5. [Eldorado Resort Casino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eldorado_Resort_Casino), Reno
>  6. [Sian Ka'an](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sian_Ka'an), Tulum
>  7. [Estadio Garcilaso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estadio_Garcilaso), Cusco
>  8. [African Renaissance Monument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_Renaissance_Monument), Dakar
>  9. [Oran 1 University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oran_1_University), Oran
>  10. [Flaminio Obelisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flaminio_Obelisk), Rome
>  11. [Lauba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauba), Zagreb
>  12. [Ile aux Cygnes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ile_aux_Cygnes), Paris
>  13. [Rogier Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogier_Tower), Brussels
>  14. [Ransomes Sports Pavilion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ransomes_Sports_Pavilion), Ipswich
>  15. [Irish Museum of Modern Art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_Museum_of_Modern_Art), Dublin
>  16. [Fossil Grove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_Grove), Glasgow
>  17. [Elbphilharmonie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbphilharmonie), Hamburg
>  18. [Museum Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Museum_Island), Berlin
>  19. [Matsesta Microdistrict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsesta_Microdistrict), Sochi
>  20. [Oman Oil and Gas Exhibition Centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oman_Oil_and_Gas_Exhibition_Centre), Muscat
>  21. [Mehrangarh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehrangarh), Jodhpur
>  22. [Osh Bazaar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osh_Bazaar), Bishkek
>  23. [Wolong Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolong_Temple), Xi'an
>  24. [Tjong A Fie Mansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tjong_A_Fie_Mansion), Medan
>  25. [SM Seaside City Cebu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SM_Seaside_City_Cebu), Cebu

Hint:

> The 25 entries can be arranged into a 5×5 table.

Comment: maybe a hint on the pattern? thanks!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Added a hint!

Comment: I wonder if anyone will ever visit all the places on that list (or have visited already). I'm assuming you haven't...?

Comment: @StewieGriffin 1/25 for me so far!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think Gladys got

> A lifetime's worth of memories

Reasoning

> Take the first letters of each answer: HETIESEAOFLIRRIFEMMOMOWTS 
>  and take an anagram to produce the answer: A LIFETIMES WORTH OF MEMORIES

Comment: You have the correct answer, but this is not how you were supposed to find it :/ Serves me right for not hiding it well enough, I suppose...

Comment: I'm on mobile so not going to check in detail, but I notice that the African Renaissance Monument is on the far west coast of Africa and Sian Ka'an is on the far east coast of Mexico... Maybe there's a left to right on the map thing going on...

Comment: @jafe maybe you can post the intended answer? im interested in that as well... :)

Comment: @Alconja That doesn't work, sadly -- I assumed the first letters would need to be sorted somehow, and so I tried latitude, longitude, year of creation / founding, country name, city name, and puzzle title. No luck with any of those.

Comment: I'm giving you the checkmark, but there's still a bounty for figuring out the intended pattern :)

Comment: @jafe Yes, fair enough, I've not figured out the ordering yet, anyway.

Answer (score 15):

The locations can be arranged into a 5x5 grid...

> ...based on the two vowels in their city names. Each city has exactly two vowels, and every combination appears once:
>
>  [image]
>
>  The final answer is just the first letter of each location, in this new order: they spell out "A LIFETIME'S WORTH OF MEMORIES".

Comment: Yes! You've got it.